# Few product restrict for specific countries

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-address

I want to restrict some products to sell in a particular country, Not all products.

Can you please suggest me how to achieve it?

Comment: You need to do customization or Use third party extension for this.

Comment: Did you solved? @Shesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a custom module to achieve this.

app/etc/modules/Custom_Productrestrict.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Productrestrict>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Custom_Productrestrict>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Custom/Productrestrict/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Productrestrict>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Custom_Productrestrict>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <productrestrict>
                <class>Custom_Productrestrict_Model</class>
               <resourceModel>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</resourceModel>
            </productrestrict>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <productrestrict_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_Productrestrict</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </productrestrict_setup>
            <productrestrict_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </productrestrict_write>
            <productrestrict_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </productrestrict_read>
        </resources>
        <helpers>
            <productrestrict>
                <class>Custom_Productrestrict_Helper</class>
            </productrestrict>
        </helpers>
        <events>
              <sales_quote_address_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <productrestrict_product>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Custom_Productrestrict_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>restrictProductByCountry</method>
                    </productrestrict_product>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_address_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
     <default>
        <catalog>
            <productrestrict>
                <enable_disable>1</enable_disable>              
            </productrestrict>
        </catalog>
    </default>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Custom/Productrestrict/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
   <sections>         
        <catalog translate="label">
            <groups>
                <productrestrict translate="label" module="productrestrict">
                    <label>Restrict Product Country</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enable_disable translate="label comment">
                            <label>Enable</label>
                            <comment>Enable/Disable extension</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enable_disable>
                    </fields>
                </productrestrict>
            </groups>                       
        </catalog>          
    </sections>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Custom/Productrestrict/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

class Custom_Productrestrict_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

    public function isEnabled()
    {       
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/productrestrict/enable_disable');
    }

}
```

app/code/local/Custom/Productrestrict/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/Custom.php

```
<?php 
class Custom_Productrestrict_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Custom
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Countryofmanufacture
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $options = parent::getAllOptions();
        $alloptions = array();
        foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
             $alloptions[] = array(
                    'label' => $option['label'],
                    'value' => $option['value']
            );
        }
        return $alloptions;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getAllOptions();
    }

    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions(false);
        foreach ($options as $item) {
            if ($item['value'] == $value) {
                return $item['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Custom/Productrestrict/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Custom_Productrestrict_Model_Observer  {

    public function restrictProductByCountry($observer) {
        if (Mage::helper('productrestrict')->isEnabled()) {
           $post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();
           if(count($post) > 0 ){
                if(isset($post['billing']) && isset($post['billing']['use_for_shipping']) && count($post['billing']) > 0 && $post['billing']['use_for_shipping']==1){
                    $country_code = $post['billing']['country_id'];
                    $this->restrict($country_code);
                }
                if(isset($post['shipping']) && count($post['shipping']) > 0){
                    $country_code = $post['shipping']['country_id'];
                    $this->restrict($country_code);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private function restrict($country_code){
            $country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($country_code);
            $products = array();
            $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
            foreach($items as $item){
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                    if($product->getId() > 0){
                        if($product->getRestrictCountries() && in_array($country_code,explode(',',$product->getRestrictCountries()))){
                                $products[] = $product->getName();
                        }
                    }

            }
            if(count($products) == 1){
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError(implode(', ',$products).' product is not allowed in "'.$country->getName().'" country.');
                $this->_redirect();
            }
            if(count($products) > 0 && count($items)  > 0){
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError(implode(', ',$products).' products are not allowed in "'.$country->getName().'" country.');
                $this->_redirect();
            }
    }
    private function _redirect(){
        $url=Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage');
        $response1 = Mage::app()->getResponse(); // observers have event args
        $response1->setRedirect($url);
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->sendResponse();
        return;
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Custom/Productrestrict/Model/Productrestrict.php

```
<?php

class Custom_Productrestrict_Model_Productrestrict extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    public function _construct() {
        $this->_init('productrestrict/productrestrict');
    }

}
```

app/code/local/Custom/Productrestrict/sql/productrestrict_setup/install-1.0.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$applyTo = array(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE,
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE
);
$installer->addAttribute(
    "catalog_product", "restrict_countries",
    array(
        "type" => "text",
        "backend" => "eav/entity_attribute_backend_array",
        'group' => 'General',
        "label" => "Restricted Countries",
        "input" => "multiselect",
        "source" => "productrestrict/product_attribute_source_custom",
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'is_visible' => 1,
        'required' => 0,
        'searchable' => 0,
        'filterable' => 0,
        'unique' => 0,
        'comparable' => 0,
        'visible_on_front' => 0,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'apply_to'          => implode(',',$applyTo),
        'note' => 'Shipping of this product will be not allowed in selected countries.'
    )
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it using the above module.

Comment: Hi, I have created a custom module but it is not reflected in the admin setting.how to configure these things.

Comment: "Restrict Product Country" is not displayed in admin panel

Comment: Did you clear cache and tried again? Also Please check if the module is enabled in System>Configuration>Advanced>Advanced.

Comment: Yes, I have checked. The module is enabled in a configuration.

Comment: I have got this exception in a report, a:5:{i:0;s:107:"Source model "productrestrict/product_attribute_source_custom" not found for attribute "restrict_countries"";i:1;s:3312:"#0 /home/xxx/public_html/Magento1/ewallet/includes/src/__default.php(44587): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "p...')

Comment: The above error usually occurs when you declare a class incorrect. Check for typo or any capital letters found mismatch. Did you change the module name? If so please check for case sensitive.

Comment: I am not changed module name "app/code/local/custom/Productrestrict/Model/" the vendor name custom of a first word is a small letter it should be capital so i have made it capital like "Custom".

Comment: Yahhh.. Thanks Developer, You made my day beautiful. it's working perfectly... Can we restrict on a CART page when customer click on estimate link?

Comment: Glad it worked well! if the customer is logged in then the product cannot be added to cart.

Comment: This functionality is not working on my end ;(

Answer (score 0):

Without requiring customization, you could create multiple websites, each with a product catalog specific to a region. Then restrict shipping methods in each website to the appropriate region.

Comment: is there any other solution? because I want to restrict only one product.